# check if sequence of function converges uniformly in closed interval

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

let $f_{n}(x) = \begin{cases}
0,  & \text{x=0} \\
\frac{x}{n} ln(\frac{x}{n}), & \text{x>0}
\end{cases} $

how can I prove that $f_{n}(x)$ uniformly converges in $[0,b]$ where $b$ is a finite number. can I use $|x-b|<\delta$ where $\delta>0$ with the regular definition of uniformity convergence?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**

$$nf'_n (x)=\ln (x/n)+1$$

the maximum  is attained  at $x_n=n/e>b $ for great enough $n $.

At $[0,b] $, the max is $f_n (b) $ which goes to zero.

Comment: Thank you Fatima. Since we know the maximum is attained at $x_{n}$ that is greater then b, can we say(?):
for every $\epsilon >0$ there is $N=\frac{x}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}$ such that $|f_{n}-0|<\epsilon$ for every $x \in [0,b]$:
$|\frac{x}{n}lnx(\frac{x}{n})| \leq \frac{x}{N}ln(\frac{x}{N}) \leq \frac{x^2}{N^2} =$ (we want) $\epsilon$

therefore, if we take $N=\frac{x}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}$ we satisfy the uniformity convergence

Comment: $|f_n (x)-0|\le |f_n (b)|<\epsilon for great enough $n $.

Comment: how can we find a certain N>0 such that for every n>N, $|f_n (x)-0|\le |f_n (b)|<\epsilon$ occurs?

Comment: @marryJ You use the fact that $\ln (n)<\sqrt {n} $

Comment: Excuse me for my bad calculus skills. can I continue developing it the following way:
$|f_n (x)-0|\leq |f_n (b)| < \frac{b}{n} ln(\frac{b}{n}) \leq \frac{b^2}{n^2} < \frac{b^2}{N^2} < \epsilon $
therefore, we take  $N = \frac{b}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}$

Comment: Yes but for large n, the logarithm is negative.

Comment: why that should be a problem? anyway, many thanks again Fatima.